# React: Using props in a rootfile for a component that contains two other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, react-functional-component

I am trying to create a component called "Question" that will contain and connect together two other components called "Question Header" and "PosterGrid" (Basically a collection of Movie Cards with the img & name of the movie, along with the list of actors).

So instead of calling in two separate components in my root "index.tsx" file, I can just call in the QuestionHeader component

However, I am not sure how to do this, and how I would use props to fill in the fields inside these components. I tried searching around, but I am still confused.

**Question Component**

```
import React from 'react';

import { Styles } from 'types/index';
import QuestionHeader from './QuestionHeader';
import PosterGrid from './PosterGrid';

interface QuestionProps {
  question: string;

}

const Question = (props: QuestionProps): JSX.Element => {
  const styles: Styles = {
    container: {
      display: 'block',
      height: 'fit-content',
      width: 'fit-content',
      padding: 'auto 0',
    },
  };

  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <QuestionHeader question={'Which movie do you like?'}/>
      <div>{PosterGrid}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Question;
```

**QuestionHeader Component**

```
import React from 'react';

import { Styles } from 'types/index';
import Colors from 'values/Colors';
import { PosterCardSize } from 'values/PosterCard';

interface QuestionHeaderProps {
  question: string;
}

const QuestionHeader = (props: QuestionHeaderProps): JSX.Element => {
  const { question } = props;

  const styles: Styles = {
    container: {
      height: `${PosterCardSize.HEIGHT}px`,
      width: `${PosterCardSize.WIDTH * 3}px`,
      backgroundColor: Colors.BLUE,
      borderRadius: '5px',
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  };

  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <p>{question}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default QuestionHeader;
```

**PosterGrid (just the relevant parts of it):**

```
const PosterGrid = (props: PosterGridProps): JSX.Element => {
  const { moviePosters } = props;
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<null | number>(null);
const moviePosterCardsTop = moviePosters
    .map((value, index) => (
      <PosterCard isSelected={index === selected} setSelected={() => setSelected(index)} moviePoster={value} />
    ))
    .slice(0, 3);
  const moviePosterCardsBottom = moviePosters
    .map((value, index) => (
      <PosterCard isSelected={index === selected} setSelected={() => setSelected(index)} moviePoster={value} />
    ))
    .slice(3);

  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <div style={styles.topPosterCardsContainer}>{moviePosterCardsTop}</div>
      <div style={styles.bottomPosterCardsContainer}>{moviePosterCardsBottom}</div>
    </div>
  );
```

**index.tsx the root file**

```
interface HomePageProps {
  theme: Theme;
}

const HomePage = (props: HomePageProps): JSX.Element => {
  const { theme } = props;

  const styles: Styles = {
    container: {
      background: theme.BACKGROUND,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
    },
  };

  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <Header theme={theme} />
      
      {/*Calling in the two components seperately, how do I pass in the values for the props below, if I just call
        in the Question component that is supposed to connect the other two components together? */}

      <QuestionHeader question="Which movie do you like best?" />
      <PosterGrid
        moviePosters={[
          {
            posterUrl: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61rv%2BRnsu6L._AC_.jpg',
            title: 'Avenger',
            videoUrl: '',
            description: 'Avenger',
            actors: ['Thor', 'Bob', 'Joe'],
          },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// HomePageProps.jsx

const HomePage = (props: HomePageProps): JSX.Element => {
  const { theme } = props;
  const moviePosters = [
          {
            posterUrl: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61rv%2BRnsu6L._AC_.jpg',
            title: 'Avenger',
            videoUrl: '',
            description: 'Avenger',
            actors: ['Thor', 'Bob', 'Joe'],
          }]
  const question = '....'
  ...
  return (
    return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <Header theme={theme} />
      <Question 
        question={question} 
        moviePosters={moviePosters}
        // your `QuestionHeader` and `PosterGrid` needed props
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
// Question.jsx

interface QuestionProps {
  question: string;
  moviePosters: moviePostersType[]
}
const Question = (props: QuestionProps): JSX.Element => {
  const {moviePosters, question } = props

  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <QuestionHeader question={question}/>
      <PosterGrid moviePosters={moviePosters} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `Question` to connect `QuestionHeader` and `PosterGrid`, then put `PosterGrid` inside `Question`, what is the point of using it separately?

```
type QuestionProps = {
  question: string
  moviePosters: PosterTypeYouHave[]
}

const Question = ({ question, moviePosters}: QuestionProps) => {
  // ...

  return (
    <div /* ... */>
      <QuestionHeader question={question} />
      {/* You wrote {PosterGrid} here which is not correct */}
      <div><PosterGrid moviePosters={moviePosters} /></div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

then use it

```
<Question question={'whatever'} moviePosters={[/* ... */]} />
```

If this is not what you want, it's not very clear to me, what is, feel free to clarify your intentions, I will update the answer. You could also make `Question` create context with some values and make `QuestionHeader` and `PosterGrid` get values from this context, but I don't see, why you would need it, it seems like an overcomplication for a pretty simple scenario you have